# Command-line controllable alarm clock programs for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line

I know I can do `sleep $[60*60*8]; open alarm.mp3` but is there perhaps a better way?

Comment: Any specific reason it needs to be command line controllable? Or is a GUI app with AppleScript (`osascript`) good enough?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least you can do

```
user@host:~$ at hh:mm
> /usr/bin/open alarm.mp3
>^D
```

which will make constantly opened terminal window unneeded.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually work in Mac OS X. In fact, `at` doesn't seem to work at all. The command is added to `atq`, but never actually run.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, generally, it requires a working atd on *nix. I have never touched OS X myself, through.

Comment: Ah ok, my previous comment was wrong... what it needs is the full path to `open`. Using `/usr/bin/open` works. (Actually since that starts iTunes by default, I used `/usr/bin/afplay` which ships with OS X.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, `sox` is also quite good if you need a bit more than just playing. I guess it's available with Homebrew.

Comment: Simple and efficient. Works on OS X, you have to start the atrun daemon though. See `man atrun`.