# How can I start/enable `at` on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, mac, at

I just noticed that `at` jobs submitted in my terminal on MacOSX are never executed:

```
$ atq
2   Fri Feb  7 12:07:00 2014
3   Mon Feb 10 10:36:00 2014
4   Sun Mar  9 09:59:00 2014
5   Mon Mar 10 13:39:00 2014
6   Tue Jul  1 10:25:00 2014
7   Mon Jun  2 22:00:00 2014
9   Thu Jun 26 13:51:00 2014
10  Thu Jul 24 08:29:00 2014
$ date
Thu Jul 10 09:22:29 CEST 2014
```

**In MacOSX, how do I enable `at` job execution?** I'm running MacOSX 10.9.3.

Vaguely related links and questions:

- http://macosx.com/forums/mac-os-x-system-mac-software/19978-does-atd-exist.html
- [Command-line controllable alarm clock programs for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/177200/command-line-controllable-alarm-clock-programs-for-mac-os-x#comment387543_177205)
- http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-40852.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working) will answer your question. To quote the relevant part:

```
To enable te needed `atrun` daemon, as `man atrun` says, execute:

  launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist

as root (e.g. via `sudo`). Once you've done that, `/var/at/` will be the key directory (though the simplest way is to use `at` as root -- e.g., once again, by `sudo`!-).
```